# How can i iterate list inside an object in spring JSTL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl, jstl-functions

I need to iterate a list inside an object. Am attaching image which contains how the object is coming on debug mode. Here is my code.

JSP:

```
<div class="sample">
    <c:forEach items="${mapPlotMaster}" var="mapplotter">
        <c:forEach items="${mapplotter}" var="customer">
            <li>${customer.cust_zip}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 model.addAttribute("mapPlotMaster", mapPlotMaster);
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004038: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/maps/mapplot.jsp at line 32 32 29: </div> 30: 31: <div class="sample"> 32: <c:forEach items="${mapPlotMaster}" var="mapplotter"> 33: <c:forEach items="${mapplotter}" var="customer"> 34: <li>${customer.cust_zip}</li> 35: </c:forEach> Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:456)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
```

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate on your problem, what is going wrong for you, is the above forEach not working

Comment: @JasonDelaney i have a list which contains three objects inside array list which is present on object mapplotter. I need to iterate list values on my JSTL. when i tried the above code am getting JSP Jasper Exception. Image will show the structure.

Comment: could you provide the stack trace for the error please

Comment: @JasonDelaney posted

Answer (score 0):

Is your mapPlotMaster object iterable? If not, you can not iterate the main object, just its array property.

I guess what you are trying to achieve is this:

```
<div class="sample">
    <c:forEach items="${mapPlotMaster.mapplotter}" var="customer">
            <li>${customer.cust_zip}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```